# Why i can't see my cardview as corner radius implemented?

Tags: kotlin

I am working on to make NoteApp with Kotlin . I have layout for recyclerview called list_item.xml. The xml design looks good both in list_item.xml and my recycler's list_item. But in phone and emulator shape has no circular borders and each two elements are connected in each other( I use staggeredgridlayout) Here is my xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/notes_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="Title"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Note"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Date"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:textColor="#606060"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My RecyclerView :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"/>
```

Code in MainActivity :

```
binding.recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.recycler.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,LinearLayout.VERTICAL)
        adapter = NotesAdapter(this,this)
        binding.recycler.adapter = adapter
```